# What is the way to prove this inequality?

Tags: calculus

Prove inequality.

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{x_i}{x_1+...+x_{i-1}+x_{i+1}+...+x_{n}} \ge \frac{n}{n-1}$$

$n \ge 2, x_j \ge 0 \ \ (j=1,...,n)$

I have proven that equality comes only when $x_1=x_2=...=x_n$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \frac{x_i}{(n-1)x_{i}} =  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n-1} = \frac{n}{n-1}$$

What should I do next?

Comment: An idea would be to assume $\sum x_i = 1$. And then apply Jensen inequality.

Comment: I dont think we can do that

Comment: But why do you think you cant do that? As long as the inequality is homogenous, such assumption are valid.

Comment: What function do you mind? ln(x)?

Comment: $\frac{x}{1-x}$. This function is convex.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $S=\sum^n_{i=1}x_i$, the inequality becomes
$$\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i}{S-x_i}\ge \frac{n}{n-1}.$$
Use Cauchy-Schwarz 
$$\left(\sum^n_{i=1}x_i(S-x_i)\right)\left(\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{x_i}{S-x_i}\right)\ge (x_1+\cdots+x_n)^2=S^2,$$
and note that
$$\sum^n_{i=1}x_i(S-x_i)=S^2-\sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2.$$